Can I cut this backwater valve access tube?
CapI am finishing my basement and want to cut this down. I would still put a cover over the top to make it accessible.

Got a pic with the cover off?

Added a couple pics. The lower cap is about 10 inches below the floor.

Based on what I see, as long as the lid can be placed without interfering with the "lower cap" there shouldn't be any problem cutting it down.  What is your intended flooring?

That's what I assumed. Thanks!

The "lower cap" has some kind of internal seal—correct?
